# Exporting api definition from AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating an entire API in AWS API Gateway. Since I'm using the graphical console, just because I'm in a learning phase, I will need some way to create the same API programmatically or via the CLI. Is there some facilities to do export the current API set in some way I can reproduce the same structure?

Comment: Is there a way to import API definitions?

Answer (score 11):

this feature is now available via CLI directly from Amazon. It produces the same output as Amazon's gui console.

**swagger**

```
aws apigateway get-export --rest-api-id a1b2c3d4e5 --stage-name dev
--export-type swagger /path/to/filename.json
```

**swagger + api gateway extensions**

```
aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='integrations'
--rest-api-id a1b2c3d4e5 --stage-name dev --export-type swagger /path/to/filename.json
```

**swagger + postman extensions**

```
aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='postman'
--rest-api-id a1b2c3d4e5 --stage-name dev --export-type swagger /path/to/filename.json
```

For details: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-export.html

Answer (score 9):

Open CLI and run following command

```
aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='apigateway' --rest-api-id **<aaaaabcdefg123>** --stage-name dev --export-type swagger latestswagger2.json
```

or

Go to stage and export it

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This feature is now generally available through the API Gateway console.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I get to it?

Comment: @RyanShillington see vaquar khan's answer above

Comment: Yup.  It was below for me, but I upvoted his answer :-).

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support for exporting your API definition with API Gateway, but this a highly requested feature and we are looking into how best to support it.

Comment: Is there a way to export my AWS API gateway using a terraform?