# How to describe AWS GatewayAPI in file and import?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We are using [Amazon Gateway API](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) and currently we describe API endpoints manually through the web console.

Is it possible to create definition of API in some file(s) and import it?

Why do we need this:

- We want every change in the API be reviewed (it's our development process) by other people.
- In case if API is deleted or broken accidently, we want to be able  to restore it easily.

By now the only solution I see is to write script, based on `aws apigateway` command line command that creates all resources and methods.
But probably there is a better way to do it?

Thanks!

P.S. It may partially overlaps with this question: [exporting api definition from AWS api gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667334/exporting-api-definition-from-aws-api-gateway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Swagger Importer feature of AWS API Gateway is what you are looking for: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/07/introducing-swagger-importer-easily-import-swagger-api-definitions-into-amazon-api-gateway/

Comment: Thanks, it was good! Also I've found out, it's possible to export API into swagger. For this one should:

- Deploy api to a stage (let's say "test")
- Go to stage "test"
- click tab "export"
- And there is option to export API into swagger + amazon integration format.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your API definition with API Gateway extensions into swagger format. Then you use the API Gateway API importer to import/update your API.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I've found it, but it was obvious, that this feature is accesible through "stages" section :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are backing your API Gateway endpoints with Lambda functions you may want to check out the serverless project https://github.com/serverless/serverless

Using this framework you have a JSON file that describes your endpoints and binds them to your Lambda code in the same project structure.  The tool lets you deploy the endpoints or code from the command line.  It also allows you to manage other AWS resources in a CloudFormation template in the same project structure and deploy it from the command line.