# How to export my settings and manually created methods and resources in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using API gate way and I have different methods with different resources. Now that I am done with them I need to export the configuration then in the future I do not have to do it manually again. However the problem is in action I only see the import option. I know for the fact that I can use swagger or API extension to first design the rest calls and then import it to API gate way. But in my case which I have created all the methods manually is there any way I can export them as a json then I can import it again in the future?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting api definition from AWS API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667334/exporting-api-definition-from-aws-api-gateway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- API Gateway currently does not support exporting your API into a
  swagger document.
- You may want to create a feature request with AWS to export the
  API as a swagger doc.
- But, you can **create** Documentation based on your current API and
  publish it from API Gateway console.

---

### **Update**

Based on comments from @MikeD, API Gateway does support exporting.

Please follow the below document from AWS:

[Export an API from API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html)

Comment: Can you please take a look at this post as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053908/saving-some-info-as-a-session-in-api-gateway-or-lamda

Comment: API Gateway does support exporting your API as a swgger doc.

Answer (score 1):

First, deploy your API to a stage.

In the API Gateway console, go to the stages page (select "Stages" under your API name in the tree view on the left.)

Click on a stage in the tree view to get to the "Stage Editor" page.

Select the "Export" tab.

On the left is an icon labeled "Export as Swagger".  Hover over it and two buttons will appear: "JSON" and "YAML".  Click the button for your preferred format.  You should get a file save dialog to download the resulting export file.